# It showing blank array when array created from each loop in click event of jquery to outside of it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, wordpress

```
tmcartepo = [];

$('input[name^="tm_option_"]').click(function () {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('input[name^="tm_option_"]:checked').each(function(){

          tmcartepo.push($(this).val());
          console.log(tmcartepo);
    });
}
```

});

```
console.log(tmcartepo);
```

This is my code and I am trying to get the value of checkbox into an array and return it to another page through ajax. But when I print that array into the scope of click method it works fine but outside of it, it's showing blank array.
When I tried console.log(tmcartepo) its showing blank array

Thank in advance

Comment: var tmcartepo is initialized as array??

Comment: this is probably another question, misunderstanding execution-order with async parts (like user interaction). I assume, you log the Array before the click happened. you have to initialize the ajax-call inside the click-handler. (or inside a function that is called in the click-handler). @ngulhane02, plz. show your actual (failing) code, including the ajax-call.

Comment: yes.It is initialized as tmcartepo = [];

Comment: I meant the ajax-call. please show this to us: `but outside of it, it's showing blank array` not the working example `when I print that array into the scope of click method it works fine`

Comment: that is exactly my point. this can't work, bacause the log() is called aeons before the click happens. You have to invoke log() **inside the click-handler**, and you have to do the same with the ajax-call.

Comment: i couldn't get you.Because i tried console.log in click & it work fine but i want to print that array outside

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to declare your variable `tmcartepo` outside the scope of click method (globally).

```
var tmcartepo;
$('input[name^="tm_option_"]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input[name^="tm_option_"]:checked').each(function(){
          tmcartepo.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(tmcartepo);
        alert(tmcartepo);
    }
});
console.log(tmcartepo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// declare variable in global scope 
var tmcartepo=[];
$('input[name^="tm_option_"]').click(function () {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('input[name^="tm_option_"]:checked').each(function(){
          tmcartepo.push($(this).val());
    });
   console.log(tmcartepo);
   alert(tmcartepo);
}  });
```